# I wonder why this simple javascript code is not running

Tags: javascript

I am facing a problem while want to, output=pick "Positive","Negative","Zero" as message if number(user puts in input box) is + or - or 0, respectively.

I am writing code- but unable that Zero is coming in message everytime, whether putting anything.

I am writing this

```js
var n1 = Number(number.value)
var finalresult;
if (n1 > 0) {
  finalresult = `Positive`
} else if (n1 == 0) {
  finalresult = `Neutral`
} else {
  finalresult = `Negative`
}

function know() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = finalresult
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number"></input>
<button id="btn" onclick=know()>Know</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Is `number` a DOM element?

Comment: Hi, your know function is not running the calculation code; so finalresult is the value set the first time

Comment: The only code that runs on the button click is `know`; all the other decisions have already been made before **and are not recalculated.**

Comment: @konekoya - Thanks to the horror of automatic DOM globals, yes. :-)

Comment: If a title of a question exists it either indicates that it is a duplicate, or that your title is too generic. You should not trick the system by just adding a `.` in front of your title. But instead, try to think of a better title summarizing what the problem is.,

Comment: As @deceze said, the issue is that you aren't re-running your code that gets the value and shows the result when you click the button. But a couple of other things: 1. [`input` elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element) are [*void elements*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#void-elements), they never have closing tags. So just `<input type="text" id="number">`, no `</input>`. 2. You're relying on the automatic DOM global for `number`. I strongly recommend **not** doing that, ...

Comment: ...  there's too much opportunity for conflicts. Look up the element on purpose via `document.getElementById` (as you did with `result`).

Comment: Thanks all ,solved and further I will try to post generic title ,instead of manipulating existing  title

Answer (score 2):

you have to recover the value of number input after it was updated

after a click on button or change event on input

```js
    function know(){
        var n1=parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);
        var finalresult;
        if(n1>0)
        {finalresult=`Positive`}
        else if(n1==0)
        {finalresult=`Neutral`}
        else
        {finalresult=`Negative`}
      document.getElementById("result").innerText=finalresult
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number" ></input>
<button id="btn" onclick=know()>Know</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: using `+` is faster than `parseInt()` :D

Comment: @Capt171 - Maybe, but A) it doesn't matter, and B) they do different things (and to my mind, neither of them does the right thing, but there we are... :-) ).

Comment: That's kinda true...

Comment: @Capt171, make it `clear` better than make it `smart`. btw, I will use `Number()` and handle 'NAN' edge case.

Comment: @ikhvjs To *a lot* of people in the JS community, `+` is very clear.

Comment: @Capt171, yes, if you are only dealing with JS. Some people may deal with different languages and sometimes feel confused by different syntax.

Comment: @Capt171 `+` vs `parseInt()` is really opinion based. The `parseInt()` (or a custom function) is a more verbose cast that is IMHO easier to see and to find in case you need to search for all locations where a cast from a string to a Number is done or to understand the types involved in a particular expression. And it is less likely that if you have a `parseInt()` that you accidentally remove it. But as I said that is opinion-based.

Comment: `+` returns `NaN` when it sees something like `2a` but `parseInt()` returns `2`. Personally, I would prefer to have `NaN` returned as `2a` *isn't* a number.

Comment: @Capt171 `To a lot of people in the JS community, + is very clear`. I agree with that but if you have `let res = +aString` and someone is in the rush of changing something a bug like having `let res = aValue + aString` is not unlikely. Sure you shouldn't do something in a rush and think twice, but that's how coding is sometimes. So having a more verbose case can help much. (There are also other patterns `let val = input || defaultValue` that people have as a mindset that works in many cases but is not actually accurate and can be problematic.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the JavaScript code into the `know()` function, so that the code is ran everytime the button is clicked and the `know()` function is triggered. In your question, `finalresult` is set when the input has no value (an empty string) and as `''` is cast to `0` when using `==`, `'' == 0` returns `true`.

```html
<input type="text" id="number" />
<button id="btn" onclick="know()">Know</button>
<p id="result"></p>
<script>
  function know() {
    var number = +document.getElementById("number").value;
    var finalresult;
    if (number > 0) {
      finalresult = `Positive`;
    } else if (number == 0) {
      finalresult = `Neutral`;
    } else {
      finalresult = `Negative`;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerText = finalresult;
  }
</script>
```

P.S. You could always consider using `===` instead of `==` (`'' === 0` returns false).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function know() {
  var n1 = +document.getElementById("number").value;
  var finalresult;
  if (n1 > 0) {
    finalresult = `Positive`
  } else if (n1 == 0) {
    finalresult = `Neutral`
  } else {`enter code here`
    finalresult = `Negative`
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = finalresult;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number"></input>
<button id="btn" onclick=know()>Know</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: AN explanation would be nice (and your code doesn't work)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite good for a beginner. The critical error was that you forgot to get the value from the input element. So, without it you don't have a value inside the `n` variable, making the code to fail.

Here is an improved version. I wrote some comments so is easier to understand.

When you are coding, you can't miss a thing. Is good to take the time to carefully build the code line by line to make sure all the pieces of the puzzle are there.

```js
// Declare the button and result elements
const resultElement = document.getElementById("result"),
      btn = document.getElementById("btn");

function know(){
   
  // Get the input element 
  const input = document.getElementById('number');

  // Get the value of the input element
  let n = input.value;
  
  if(n > 0 ){
    result = `Positive`;
  }
  else if(n === 0){
    result = `Neutral`;
  }
  else{
    result = `Negative`;
  }
  resultElement.innerText = result;
}

// It is a better practice to use event listener instead of onClick
btn.addEventListener('click', know);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number">
<button id="btn">Know</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

**Note 1:** is better to use event listener from the start because farther the line as your codes get bigger, you will en up with multiple onClick events and the code will be much clearer and easier to debug than using `onClick = someFunction()` on the HTML elements.

**Note 2:** in the conditional statement you are using two equals signs for comparing, in JS is always better two use three `===`.

**Note3:** Variables that don't change can be declared as `const`

Comment: `Variables that don't change can be declared as const` so why are `input` and `n` not `const` in your code? Where is `result` declared?

Comment: `It is a better practice to use event listener instead of onClick` yes `addEventListener` is generally better than `onclick` but both are event listeners.

Comment: Why do you have `input = document.getElementById('number');` inside of the the function but `resultElement = document.getElementById("result")` out side of it?

Comment: @t.niese well, that was the main error of the OP. I wanted to make the code easy to understand. If I declare all the elements at the top it may be less intuitive code in my opinion.